# Can MapStruct map two collections of different types into one collection by key?

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have two collections of different types and want to map to a third collection type. For example, I have a `Set<Model>` and a `Set<Make>` that I want to map to `Set<CarDto>`.

I have a mapper that maps the two parameterized types to the third type:

```
@Mapping(source = "model.name", target = "modelName")
@Mapping(source = "make.name", target = "makeName")
CarDto from(Model model, Make make);
```

`Model` and `Make` both have a `carId` property. I use it to tie them to the same `CarDto`.

I know I can iterate over both sets and call `from(model, make)` when both objects have the same `carId`.

```
for(Make make: makes) {
    for (Model model : models) {
        if (make.getCarId() = model.getCarId()) {
             carDtoSet.add(mapper.from(make, model));
        }
    }
 }
```

But is there a way to have MapStruct do this?

I found `@IterableMapping` and it has `elementMappingControl` but I'm not sure how that can help.

Comment: It sounds like it ought to be possible. Do you have some sample code where you have tried it?

Comment: @jonhanson - Just the code above where I iterate over the two collections. I'm not sure how to use MapStruct to do this